# cmake find_package cannot locate glfw after build and install

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to use cmake's find_package function to find the installation of glfw3 and I'm not quite sure I'm understanding the instructions. I've download glfw3 and followed the instructions for building.

downloaded the src, went to the root, and ran `cmake ..`

Then I open the main solution `glfw.sln` in visual studio. I built the solution and everything seemed to build fine. I can see where the lib was created and everything. In my own cmake project, when I use `find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)` I receive this error:

```
By not providing "Findglfw.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "glfw", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glfw" with any of
the following names:

glfwConfig.cmake
glfw-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "glfw" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"glfw_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "glfw"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
```

I was under the impression that once I ran and installed another cmake library that it was to be included in other projects like glfw3, it would install a glfw3config.cmake somewhere where any call to cmake can find it. Is there a reason why that is not happening? Where is this folder that contains the *config.cmake normally located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because you built `gflw3` but didn't do the Windows/Visual Studio equivalent of `make install` so the artifacts are not deployed to a location which `cmake` knows to look for.

You should pass a suitable directory with `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=` when invoking `cmake` for `glfw3` and then reference it in `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=` for your own project. Basically:

1. Configure your `gflw3` project where to install its output artifacts with `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/Users/me/gflw3` when running `cmake` for it.
2. Build `gflw3` & deploy/install it.
3. Tell your own project to look for things in `C:/Users/me/gflw3` with `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/Users/me/gflw3` when running `cmake` for it.

Comment: I thought the point of find_package and config was to remove the need for an end user to specify the location of the library/module. If they require the end user to specify the location of the config file anyway, why not just make them manipulate the generated makefile or vcproj file to point to the library. Isn't cmake supposed to abstract this? I just want it so that when people run `cmake .` on my project, it finds the libraries installed and generates vcproj / makefiles with the dependencies already enumerated. What is the way to go about doing this?

Comment: @FatalCatharsis it is. But `find_package()` is not magic: it looks in a set of well-known directories to find packages, and you can extend it by setting the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable. Additionally the default set of these well-known directories is OS-specific but generally part of the OS/vendor directory trees. This may present issues w.r.t. file/directory permissions when trying to install things you build from source. You can use `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to work around *that*.